# Restart-Computer to Email Body = Null, PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Attempting to run the follow script for a reboot I get the following error,

```
"Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an arg
that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At line:8 char:30
+             Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage"
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks
Cody

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName nocconverter1 -Wait -For Wmi 
$server = 'XXX'
ping -n 2 $server >$null
Function Server_Status_Check {
                if($lastexitcode -eq 0) {
            write-host "$server is ONLINE" 
        } else {
            write-host "$server is OFFLINE/UNREACHABLE"
}          
}


$messageParameters = @{                        
                Subject = "Result: Reboot report for WebPeriop  - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"                        
                Body = Server_Status_Check | out-string
                From = "XXXX"                        
                To = "XXXXX"                        
                SmtpServer = "exmbx6"                        
            }                        
            Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the display.  It doesn't write to stdout out therefore your Server_Status_Check function outputs nothing.  Change it to:

```
Function Server_Status_Check {
    if($lastexitcode -eq 0) {
        "$server is ONLINE" 
    } 
    else {
        "$server is OFFLINE/UNREACHABLE"
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem.  In general, use `Write-Host` very sparingly and only when you want the end user to see something that never needs to be captured to a variable or logged to a file.